# Error after deleting all cache in Magento 2

Tags: error, magento-2.1, code-generation, autoloader

On deleting all cache as

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/generation/*
```

I got below error

```
Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in vendor\magento\framework\Code\Generator\EntityAbstract.php on line 152

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in vendor\magento\framework\Autoload\ClassLoaderWrapper.php on line 81

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php on line 317

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php on line 349
exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Source class "" for   "Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor" generation does not exist.'
in vendor\magento\framework\Code\Generator.php:185 Stack trace:     #0  
vendor\magento\framework\Code\Generator.php(112): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->tryToLoadSourceClass('Magento\\Framewo...', Object(Magento\Framework\Interception\Code\Generator\Interceptor)) #1 
vendor\magento\framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\\Framewo...') #2 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\\Framewo...') #3 
vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(93): spl_autoload_call('Magento\\Framewo...') #4 
vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #5 
vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php(130): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...') #6 
vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php(67): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Framewo...') #7     
vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #8 
vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(233): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #9 
index.php(38): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\\Framewo...') #10 {main}
```

What are the reasons behind this issue?

Can you suggest me the possible solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 19):

You have to first remove **var** folder.

Run command, `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

After remove var folder give permission to var folder,

```
chmod -R 775 var/generation/ var/cache/ var/full_page/
```

Check again.

Comment: The error solved for me on compiling modules using **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

Comment: I have same issue and my issue also resolved using  php bin/magento setup:di:compil comand

Answer (score 6):

If you're still having issues after compiling, removing the var/di folder & contents usually does the trick for me. No idea what actually causes this to happen though, I frequently run into it and would very much like to know.

Comment: Have you managed to find out why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by giving the var directory 777 in permissions

```
cd magento root folder
sudo chmod 777 -R var/
```

now Magento can create di folder.

Answer (score 0):

I also same problem below worked for me

```
cd <your Magento install dir> 
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
chown -R :www-data .   // I used LEMP/LAMP
chmod u+x bin/magento

php bin/magento setup:di:compile   // you can skip if know compile status
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_CA // if need your language code
```